# what the effect of javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm learning javascript closure,I have read many examples about closure,but i still confused in why we must be use closure?

here is an example i copied from "The Good Parts"

```
 var myObject = function(){
   var value = 0;

   return {
        increment: function(inc){
             value += inc;
        },
        getValue: function(){
             return value;
        }
   }

 };
  var obj1 =myObject();    
  document.write(obj1.getValue()); //0
  obj1.increment(10);
  document.write(obj1.getValue());//10
```

But i wonder why we shouldn't write like that?

```
    var myObject = function(){
    var value = 0;


     this.increment= function(inc){
          value += inc;
     },
     this.getValue= function(){
          return value;
     }

  };
   var obj1 =new myObject(); 
   document.write(obj1.getValue());
   obj1.increment(10);
   document.write(obj1.getValue());
```

first time ask question,poor english,forgive me !

Comment: Also read this: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the closure is concerned the syntax are equivalent.

*However* if you want your object to be typed you must use the second syntax.

With the first syntax you will have:

```
obj1 instanceof myObject === false.
```

Making it *kind of* a singleton.

Whereas the second syntax will give you :

```
obj1 instanceof myObject === true
```

Making your object an instance of myObject

Answer (score 0):

That works fine. Both methods use a closure to contain the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are helpful when you need to access a value inside an object that no longer is in scope. When you are using the code from The Good Parts, the variable `value` will be incremented each time you are using `increment`, although the function `myObject` has returned.